# Is there any way to change theme mode of App(UI) to dark or light dynamically based on user's Local time using React-Native?

Tags: react-native, themes

I have tried Bellow code but still no luck ...

I'm getting the error: `AppThemeState` is `undefined` .

```
import { AppThemeState } from 'react-native';


const bannerContainerStyle =
AppThemeState.currentTheme === 'dark' ? styles.mainContainerViewDark : styles.mainContainerViewLight;
```

Comment: Do you want to change your app's theme (i.e UI ) or phone's theme (currently not directly possible from app)?

Comment: I want change apps theme if its night then it should change to dark otherwise it should be light

Comment: Are u solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const getCurrentAuTime = () => {
  return moment
    .duration(
      moment
        .default()
        .tz('Australia/Melbourne')
        .format('HH:mm:ss'),
    )
    .asSeconds();
  //return 32401;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be in `dark mode` in the `evening` and `light` in the `morning`, depending on local time, you can:

```js
var themColor = ""
var hours = new Date().getHours();
if (hours >20 || hours < 5) {
   themColor = "dark"
} else {
   themColor = "light"
}
const bannerContainerStyle = themColor === "dark" ? styles.mainContainerViewDark : styles.mainContainerViewLight;
```

There are methods to receive and process current location information through GPS, but I will introduce simple method. Receive and process device usage language information.

**You can run**

```
$ npm install --save react-native-localize
# --- or ---
$ yarn add react-native-localize
//Don't forget to run pod install after that !
```

### Usage

```js
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

const localCode =  RNLocalize.getLocales()
const countryCode = localCode.countryCode
if (countryCode === "IN" && hours >17 || countryCode === "IN" && hours < 5) {
   themColor = "dark"
} else if (countryCode === "AU" && hours > 19 || countryCode === "AU" && hours < 5)  {
   themColor = "dark"
} else {
   themColor = "light"
}
```

Comment: just assume my application is being used in both Australia  and India . For India sunset time is 17:00 but for Australia  its 19:00 . so how to handle these kind of scenario .?

Comment: @Avinashnayak I updated my answer to answer in your comments.

Comment: thanks , but my application can be used from any country and I cant hard code data for all those country . That's the issue man :(